# Is there a way to make nginx terminate a websocket connection and pass only the socket stream to a server?

Tags: nginx, websocket

Basically what I'm trying to do is have a secure websocket connection start life at a client, go through nginx where nginx would terminate the tls, and instead of just proxying the websocket connection to a server, have nginx handle the websocket upgrade and just send the socket stream data to a tcp server or a unix domain socket.

Is that possible with the existing nginx modules and configuration?

proxy_pass can connect to a server via a unix domain socket

`proxy_pass http://unix:/tmp/backend.socket:/uri/;`

But the implication is that it still speaks http over the unix domain socket and the server is responsible for handling the websocket upgrade. I'm trying to get nginx to do the upgrading so that only the raw socket stream data gets to my server.

Sorta like a mix between proxy_pass and fastcgi_pass.

Do I have to modify one of these modules to make that possible or is there some way to configure this to work?

Comment: Can you user lua for scripting? Consider checking: https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-websocket

Comment: well all options are on the table at the moment, but lua wouldn't be my first choice. I'll take a look though, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So what I eventually came to realize is that proxies just proxy and don't parse protocols. There's nothing built into nginx (although mod_ws in apache might do it) that can actually process the websockets protocol, the nginx proxy function just forwards the stream to the back end server. I'm working on another approach for this as the hope of having the webserver do the heavy lifting is not going to work easily.

Comment: The websocket protocol makes it very hard to do a simple conversion, as the websocket protocol is pascket-oriented and has packets/frames of different types, so you will always need a higher level protoocl to communicate packet boundaries and types, preclusing the use of a simple "transparent" stream connection such as TCP. There si something nginx can do though, and it already does: TLS handling, so at least that work can be moved to the webserver.  However, it's not true that nginx speaks HTTP on the forwarded socket - the websocket protoocol initially looks like HTTP, but it isn't.